# Proving an equality holds with modulus satisfying certain conditions

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $|v|=1$. Show that the following equality holds.

$$\left|\frac{u-v}{1-\bar{u}v}\right| = 1.$$

I can't seem to convert this into a suitable result. My aim is to convert the LHS into something simply depending on $|v|$.

\begin{align}
\left|\dfrac{u-v}{1-\bar{u}v}\right| &= \dfrac{|u-v|}{|1-\bar{u}v|} \\ &= \dfrac{|v(u\bar{v}-1)|}{|1-\bar{u}v|} \\ &= \dfrac{|v||u\bar{v}-1|}{|1-\bar{u}v|} \\ &= \dfrac{|v||u\bar{v}(1-\bar{u}v)|}{|1-\bar{u}v|} \\ &= \dfrac{|v||u||\bar{v}||1-\bar{u}v|}{|1-\bar{u}v|} \\ &= |v||u||\bar{v}| = |u|.
\end{align}

And from here I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note:

$$\dfrac{|v||u\bar{v}-1|}{|1-\bar{u}v|} = \dfrac{|v||1 - u\bar{v}|}{|1-\bar{u}v|}  = \dfrac{|v||\overline{1 - u\bar{v}}|}{|1-\bar{u}v|}$$

Comment: That is exactly what I did on line 4. It does not cancel to a suitable result.

Comment: Indeed I don't think your line four is correct. You can write $|u\bar v -1 | = |u\bar v (1- \bar u v)|$ only when you know $|u| = 1$. @MichaelHowlard

Comment: On that line I have used the fact that $u\bar{u} = 1$ and $v\bar{v}=1$ simultaneously, this does not use the assumption that $|u|=1$. using your version where would you continue on your next step?

Comment: Note that we only have $u \bar u= |u|^2$, if you use $u\bar u =1$, you implicitly assumed that $|u|=1$. @MichaelHowlard

Answer (score 0):

For all $u\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{v\}$, we have
$$
  \frac{u-v}{1-\overline{u}v} = \frac{u - v}{v\overline{v} - \overline{u}v} 
  = \frac{u - v}{v(\overline{v} - \overline{u})}.
$$
The conclusion follows from $\lvert v \rvert = 1$ and $\lvert u - v \rvert = \lvert \overline{v} - \overline{u} \rvert$.

Comment: Can you prove your second statement $|u-v| = |\bar{v} - \bar{u}|$?

Comment: @MichaelHowlard: Sure, $\lvert\overline{v} - \overline{u}\rvert = \lvert \overline{u} - \overline{v}\rvert = \lvert \overline{u - v} \rvert = \lvert u - v\rvert$.

Answer (score 0):

*A variant:*

This equality is equivalent to $\lvert u-v\rvert^2=\lvert1-\bar uv\rvert^2$. Now

- $\lvert u-v\rvert^2=(u-v)(\bar u-\bar v)=u\bar u-u\bar v-\bar uv+v\bar v=u\bar u-u\bar v-\bar uv+1$;
- $\lvert1-\bar uv\rvert^2=(1-\bar uv)(1-u\bar v)=1-u\bar v-\bar u v+u\bar uv\bar v=1-u\bar v-\bar u v+u\bar u.$